# A question of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

For each positive integer $n$, the mean of first $n$ terms is $n$. What is the 17th term of the sequence?
Now, how to find the sum since any particular series is not specified?

Comment: Any thoughts?  What's $a_1$?  What's $a_2$?

Comment: @lulu nope I don't know! What will it be?

Comment: What's the mean of the first two terms? What's... er... the mean of the first **one** term(s)?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}=n \rightarrow S=a_1+a_2+...+a_n=n^2$$

So,

$$a_{17}=(a_1+a_2+...+a_{17})-(a_1+a_2+...+a_{16})$$

**Can you finish?**

For a general approach you can write:

$$a_n=(a_1+a_2+...+a_{n})-(a_1+a_2+...+a_{n-1})=n^2-(n-1)^2=2n-1$$

And the sum is of course given by:

$$S=a_1+a_2+...+a_{n}=n^2$$

Comment: @Lokesh Sangewar: is it clear?

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}{n} = n$$
so:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k = n^2$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k = (n-1)^2$$
$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k = n^2-(n-1)^2 = (n+n-1)(n-n+1)=2n-1$$

We have then
$$a_{17}=2\cdot 17-1 = 33$$

Comment: How did u get that last expression An=?

Comment: @LokeshSangewar $\sum_{k=1}^na_k = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k+a_n$

Answer (score 0):

Let the $r$-th term, $a_r=f(r)$.

Given that the average of the first $n$ terms is $n$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\frac 1n\sum_{r=0}^n f(r)&=n\\
\sum_{r=0}^n f(r)&=n^2\\
f(n)&=n^2-(n-1)^2=2n-1\\
f(17)&=\color{red}{33}\end{align}$$